# Jenkins Artifactory plugin: artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude equivalent for declarative pipelines

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

In a scripted Jenkins pipeline I used the following functionality:

```
rtMaven.deployer.artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude("frog*")
```

What is the equivalent way to do it in a declarative pipeline?

The [declarative](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-MavenBuildswithArtifactory) examples on the wiki makes no mention of it, whereas the [scripted](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-MavenBuildswithArtifactory) examples do.

Clearly, looking at the souce of the plugin, the functionalty I want is there, and I don't know how to invoke it.

https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/blob/ebce86efdf1e1a7c38a9ad1ed6a8063b58ecdf3a/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/declarative/steps/maven/MavenDeployerStep.java#L26

Working, scripted code:

```
server = Artifactory.server("myServer")
rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
rtMaven.tool = config.toolMaven // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo: "libs-release-local", snapshotRepo: "libs-snapshot-local", server: server
rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo: "libs-release", snapshotRepo: "libs-snapshot", server: server
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false // Disable artifacts deployment during Maven run
if (config.includeFilterPattern) {
    rtMaven.deployer.artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude(config.includeFilterPattern)
}
buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
buildInfo.name = "myBuild"
buildInfo.env.capture = true
```

My declarative code currently looks like this:

```
rtMavenResolver (
        id: "resolver-id",
        serverId: "myServer",
        releaseRepo: "libs-release",
        snapshotRepo: "libs-snapshot"
)

rtMavenDeployer (
        id: "deployer-id",
        serverId: "myServer",
        releaseRepo: "libs-release-local",
        snapshotRepo: "libs-snapshot-local"
)

rtBuildInfo (
        captureEnv: true,
        buildName: "myBuild"
)

//... mvn clean install

rtPublishBuildInfo (
        serverId: "myServer"
)
```

Comment: Just wrap the call in a `script{ }` block.

Comment: Also from the doc: "When working with the Jenkins Artifactory plugin, be sure to choose either scripted or declarative. In other words, do not use declarative and scripted steps within a single pipeline. This will not work."

Comment: So, thanks, but unless you've got a working example, I don't think it's as simple as that

Comment: How I read that is that you should not mix declarative and scripted steps of Artifactory but you are still allowed to use all-scripted Artifactory steps in a declarative pipeline. So you could basically do everything as you were used in scripted pipeline, except that you wrap that code in `script` blocks. Might not be as "clean" as pure declarative syntax but you could always wrap scripted code into your own higher-level declarative steps defined in a shared library.

Comment: That I agree with, and have done so in the past.  I guess this is more an exercise of using the pure-declaritive style, and finding it lacking.

Comment: It isnt that its lacking, it is that plugin developers need to extend and implement certain classes to enable the use in declarative pipelines. seems like extra work when we have script blocks.

Comment: If I were to just start using the plugin for the first time ever, I would probably start with declraritive, and the docs along with it.  The docs for declaritive are lacking in that there is no mention of the functionality I know I'd like to use.  I'm aware of what I could do as a workaround, but that's not really my question.  If it's not possible, I'll use the scripted method, but so far all comments just say "use workaround" instead of "yes, do x for pure declarative" or "no, not possible".  Anyway, thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple once you know how (Not documented at the time of writing):

```
rtMavenDeployer (
        id: "deployer-id",
        serverId: "myServer",
        releaseRepo: "libs-release-local",
        snapshotRepo: "libs-snapshot-local",
        includePatterns: ["frog*"]
)
```

Comment: hello Denham, may I please ask you for a assistance on the similar issue matter?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091613/jenkins-convert-current-declarative-pipeline-to-maven-upload-pipeline